# cordova keep socket.io running in background with ussing batery

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Im developing a cordova APP for Android, the APP uses socket.io to connect to a node server and send and receive notifications from the server, like wassap APP.

Wehn i set the APP in the background, my socket close the connection, but setting  in the config.xml allow me to get the APP running in background.

But, if I unplug the USB from the phone, the socket close after the 10 seconds (my server pingTimeout config) if the APP are in background mode.

Im looking for inbo about APP dont keep running in background using the Batery, but dont found nothing.

Someone expect these problem? Im Using Apache Cordova 5.3.3

Comment: you could probably use serviceWorkers instead of WebSockets when in BG mode, but that's going to be a lot more complicated and less supported. you might also consider a commercial "push service" for when the app is not running. But to directly answer the question: NO, if you're in the BG, sockets and your code will be more or less shut down.

Comment: Then if I understand, i need to create a service in NATIVE java, and run in the service the websocket (http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/) and then i can call javascript method in the "background cordova" ? If this can be possible its an option, i need to modify some code but dont remake all, only control socket in java and call methods in the javascript.